# how to insert and delete multiple rows by comparing with old data in table in cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I have a table that has some field as image below.
I have some new rows to insert in that table

1. customer_register_id = 2, language_id=1
2. customer_register_id = 2, language_id=3
3. customer_register_id = 2, language_id=4

I don’t want to delete old row in my table. I want to update on existing row
and insert new row automatically if row doesn’t existed and delete old row if that row does’t have in my new field list.

[image]

Comment: `and delete old row if that row does’t have in my new field list.` ... can you elaborate on what this actually means?

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare every new row value with old rows values and then delete or insert it. You should make a single select all query and add each selected value in an array and after compare. I think this is the most efficient way . If u  didn't understand just say me and will explain you more.